# Get main content in a page while web scraping node js, Puppeteer, Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

I have a Project with **Node JS** on web scraping where I will have to scrape Heading and Text from Main Content. But the Problem is I'm not able to Determine which is Main Content When there is No `aside` or `main` tag or class/id/role named `aside` or `main`. I'm Using **Puppeteer** and **Cheerio** Library. I have Tried using Mercury Web Parser But it has its Own problems. Like It doesn't return any content from Pages that Built with Elementor Theme builder on Wordpress. If anyone have any idea on how can I differentiate main content from rest of the web page it will be really helpful.

Comment: Please provide more details like URL, or HTML sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout [Readability JS](https://github.com/mozilla/readability) library from Mozilla. They use for reader view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to explore more about CSS Selectors and specificity.
If you're scraping Elementor, be sure to use this trick for the selector:
Use `data-elementor-(attributename)` attributes for everything in DOM.

```
const mainContent = await page.waitForElement('[data-elementor-type="wp-page"]', {visible: true, timeout: 0})
```